# Commerce server thread abort

Tags: commerceserver2007

Anyone know of issues where the pipeline call fails quite often and errors such as this are generated

Mojave pipeline call failure.

System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.

What is my issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose if you were doing a response.redirect or server. Transfer in the pipeline code somewhere u might see this